# How to allow desktop to be used in Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: kubuntu, 15.04

Hi guys I recently installed Kubuntu 15.04 and I cant for the life of me figure out to to unlock the desktop so that I can drag and drop files there. Its an important part of my workflow and I would hate to loose this functionality. I have read a few posts saying that right clicking on the desktop and going to Desktop Settings -> Activities will enable this but I don't have "activities" as an option. Do I need to install a package? Any advice would be great!

(I tried to post a screen shot but my rep is too low)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Documents**

KDE Userbase Plasma: https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma

**To start**

Right click the desktop - unlock the widgets if they are locked

[image]

Left click the toolbox or right click the desktop - pick the Desktop Settings.

[image]

Change the Wallpaper type to Folder View

[image]

Comment: Oh thank you! I knew it had to be there somewhere. Can't believe I didn't check that drop down. Thanks again!